# Scanning string with length restriction

Tags: c

Using the standard C library, is there a way to scan a string (containing no whitespace) from standard input only if it fits in a buffer? In the following example I would like *scanCount* to be 0 if the input string is larger than 32:

```
char str[32];
int scanCount;

scanCount = scanf("%32s", str);
```

Edit: I also need file pointer rollback when the input string is too large.

Comment: This means, you expect an `EOF` for the next read? And should be `scanf("%31s", str)` for the 0-terminator.

Comment: Do you need the file pointer to rollback to the original position if the input string exceeds 32 characters?

Comment: Yes, the file pointer should rollback upon failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified a requirement to only read if the whole data fits your buffer. This requirement makes no sense at all as it doesn't provide any functionality to your program. You can easily achieve the same sort of tasks without it. It also is not how operating systems present files to the user applications.

You can simply create a buffer of any size you see fit and then you can keep the data in the buffer until you can handle it, or you can do magic like actually resizing the buffer to accomodate more incoming data.

You can read any number of characters from a file using the ANSI `fread()` function:

```
size_t count;
char buffer[50];

count = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, stdin);
```

You can then see how many characters have actually been read by looking at the `count` variable, you can fill in the final `NUL` character if it's less than the buffer size or you can decide what to do next, if the whole buffer has been read and more data may be availabe. You could of course read `sizeof buffer - 1` instead, to be able to always finalize the string. When the count is smaller than your specified value, `feof()` and `ferror()` can be used to see what happened. You can also look at the actual and check for a LF character to see how many lines you have read.

When using an enlarging buffer, you will need `malloc()` or just create a NULL pointer that will later be allocated using `realloc()`:

```
/* Set initial size and offset. */
size_t offset = 0;
size_t size = 0;
char *buffer = NULL;
```

When you need to change the size of the buffer, you can use `realloc()`:

```
/* Change the size. */
size = 100;
buffer = realloc(buffer, size);
```

(The first time it's equivalent to `buffer = malloc(size)`.)

You can then read data into the buffer:

```
size_t count = fread(buffer + offset, 1, size - offset, stdin);
count += offset;
```

(The first time it's equivalent to `fread(buffer, 1, size, stdin)`.)

When finished, you should free the buffer:

```
free(buffer);
```

At any time, you still have all the already read data somewhere in a buffer, so you can get back to it at any time, you just decouple the reading and processing, where the above examples are all about *reading*.

The processing then depends on what you need. You generally need to identify the start and end of the data that you want to extract.

Example start and end, where end means one character after the last one you want, so the arithmetics work better:

```
size_t start = 0;
size_t end = 10;
```

Extract the data (using bits of C99):

```
char data[end - start + 1];
memcpy(data, buffer + start, end - start);
data[end] = '\0';
```

Now you have a NUL-terminated string containing the data you wanted to extract. Sometimes you just assume `start = 0` and then want to consume the data from the buffer to make place for new data:

```
char data[end + 1];
/* copy out the data */
memcpy(data, buffer, end);
/* move data between end end offset to the beginning */
memmove(buffer, buffer + end, offset - end);
/* adjust the offset accordingly */
offset -= end;
```

Now you have your data extracted but you still have the buffer ready with the rest of the data you haven't processed, yet. This effectively achieves what you wanted, as by keeping the data in an intermediate buffer, you're effectively peeking into an arbitrary part of the data received on input and taking out the data only if it fits your expectations, doing whatever else if they don't.Of course you should carefully test all return values to check for exceptional conditions and such stuff.

I personally would also turn all indexes in the examples into pointers directly to the memory and adjust the arithmetics accordingly, but not everyone enjoys pointer arithmetics as I do ;). I also tend to prefer low-level POSIX API over the intermetiate layer in form of the ANSI API. Ready to fix bugs or improve explanations, please comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment that you need the file pointer reset on scan failure makes this impossible to do with `scanf()`.

`scanf()` is basically specified as "`fscanf( stdin, ... )`", and `fscanf()` is *defined* to "[push] back at most one input character onto the input stream" (C99, footnote 242). (I assume this is for the same reason that `ungetc()` is only required to support one byte of push-back: So that it can be conveniently buffered in memory.)

`*scanf()` is a poor choice to read uncertain inputs, for the reason described above and several other shortcomings when it comes to recovery-from-error. Generally speaking, if there is *any* chance that the input might not conform to the expected format, read input into an internal memory buffer first and then parse it from there.

Comment: Upvoting as this says the most important bits, proposing my own answer to show some of the actual techniques used to achieve that.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda: I considered writing up a longer answer myself, but got sidetracked. ;) Good work, +1.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. I though *scanf* was capable of putting back all read characters.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: That would indeed be most comfortable, but consider the case where multiple programs are piped together... unlimited put-back would require *every* program in the pipe to effectively buffer *all* the data...

Answer (score 0):

Just read and store one character too many, and test for that.

```
char str[34];    // 33 characters + NUL terminator
int scanCount = scanf("%33s", str);
if (scanCount > 0 && strlen(str) > 32)
{
    scanCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: The thing is I need the file pointer to rollback like scanf does when the conversion fails.

Comment: good occasion to point out to never use `strlen`, and to prefer `strnlen` instead. (same goes for all `str*`, to replace with `strn*`)

Comment: @njzk2: 1) If you *know* that the string *is* properly terminated, checking for overflow is wasting time. 2) `strnlen()` is non-standard. 3) The Big `strncpy()` Surprise, a.k.a. blindly replacing `str*` with `strn*` is an invitation for trouble.

Comment: @DevSolar: you *know* the string is properly terminated until someone changes it and you don't know anymore. using `strcpy` is an invitation to buffer overflow exploits. don't blindly replace things. just don't use `str*`

Comment: @njzk2: If it's a string, it's zero terminated. If it's not zero terminated, it's not a string and has no business this side of your input verification (during which you may well have use for `strn...()` functions, I grant you that, but they *should* have been named `mem..()`). But if you've checked `strlen()` before, doing it again with `strncpy()` is redundant, costs performance, *and* invites an off-by-one error stranding you with a string that is *no longer* zero terminated. Buffer overflows are a problem. The solution is proper engineering, not condemning perfectly servicable functions.

Comment: @njzk2: And please, *do* look up the pecularities of `strncpy()`. Of all the `strn...()` functions, it is the *least* useful, and the most surprising.

Comment: @DevSolar "If the input exceeds the field width, the contents of str will __not be zero-terminated__" I don't think so. Go reading the manual page and show me what makes you so confident.

Comment: @starrify: Blimey. Actually I *did* look up the man page (*because* I wasn't confident), and apparently picked out the only one that wasn't clear about the zero byte added at (FIELDWIDTH + 1) in case of overflow. Checking with the C99 standard, the wording is *quite* clear, so I revoke that statement. (I stand to the other things I said.)

Comment: @DevSolar: `strncpy` does have pitfalls you need to watch out for, but it is way safer that `strcpy`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: There's IMO no rollback you could expect from `scanf()`, the only rollback I know of is that the ANSI file API allows for buffering back one character. You could theoretically move your position in an actual file but you can't do anything better than buffering with a generic input stream and especially not with stdin.

Answer (score 0):

On scanning a stream such as `stdin` is only allowed to "put back" up to 1 `char`.  So scanning 32 or 33 `char` and then undoing is not possible.

If your input could use `ftell()` and `fseek()` (Available when `stdin` is redirected), code could

```
long pos = ftell(input);
char str[32+1];
int scanCount;
scanCount = fscanf(input, "%32s", str);
if (scanCount != 1 || strlen(str) >= 32) {
  fseek(input, pos, SEEK_SET);
  scanCount = fscanf(input, some_new_format, ....); 
}
```

Otherwise use `fgets()` to read a maximal line and use `sscanf()`

```
char buf[1024];
if (fget(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_IOError_or_EOF();

char str[32+1];
int scanCount;
scanCount = sscanf(buf, "%32s", str);
if (scanCount != 1 || strlen(str) >= 32) {
  scanCount = sscanf(buf, some_new_format, ....); 
}
```